# Error incompatible types: String cannot be converted

Tags: java

intento ejecutar el siguiente programa pero me da el error

> " error: incompatible types: String cannot be converted to char"  if
>   (sexo == 'H') sexo = " Hombre "; en varios apartados.  y " error:
>   cannot find symbol: System.out.println("Nombre: " + a.getNombre() + "
>   " + a.apellido());

Alguien podria ayudarme?

Gracias

Answer (score 0):

El primer error es porque 'H' no es un string, sino que es un char.  Para hacerlo correcto deberías poner comillas, algo así:

```
if (sexo.compareTo("H") == 0) sexo = " Hombre ";
```

El segundo error dependerá de la interfaz de tu clase, pero imagino que lo que falta es el "get" para obtener el apellido, quedando algo así:

```
System.out.println("Nombre: " + a.getNombre() + " " + a.getApellido());
```

Suerte!

Comment: Muchas gracias por contestar Gustavo. Tengo bien puesto pero me siguen apareciento todos tipo asi "java:30: error: bad operand types for binary operator '!='
                if (sexo != "H") sexo = Desconocido; y otro tipo java:32: error: incompatible types: char cannot be converted to String
                return sexo; Estoy empezando en esto de la programacion y estoy un poco perdida la verdad. Muchas gracias.

Comment: Perdón @PILAR, me confundí de lenguaje, en Java tenés que utilizar compareTo, ya modifiqué el código para que te funcione.  Acá se explica el uso de compareTo: https://beginnersbook.com/2013/12/java-string-compareto-method-example/.

Comment: En java también puedes usar ** equals** que para el caso me parece más adecuado

Answer (score 0):

> error: incompatible types: String cannot be converted to char

El problema radica en que 'H' se define como carácter y sexo esta definido como un String. Intenta utilizar el metodo compareTo para comparar dos cadenas

```
If(sexo.compareTo("H") == 0)
```

> error: cannot find symbol: System.out.println("Nombre: " + a.getNombre() + " " + a.apellido());

Verifica que tu objeto "a" tenga el metodo getNombre() y apellido(), puede que hayas definido el método getApellido y no lo estés usando.